# Openpyxl skip over first line

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to skip over the first line of the spreadsheet (the header), using a solution I found from an answer to the same question. From what I understood, the solution said to add in `use_iterators=True` when loading the workbook and then add in `.iter_rows(row_offset=2)`. When I try make use of the function below, I get an error saying: `load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_iterators'`

```
def Text_Box_Type(self, workbook, worksheet):
    self.wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(workbook, use_iterators=True)
    self.ws = self.wb[worksheet]

    for row in self.ws.iter_rows(row_offset=2):
        FieldName = row[1].value
        FieldValue=row[2].value
        Name=self.driver.find_element_by_name(FieldName)
        Name.clear()
        Name.send_keys(FieldValue)
```

Please will someone advise me how to skip over the first row of the sheet?

Answer (score 3):

This answer may be late but I found this solution and I hope it works for you

Up to version 2.4 use_iterators keyword was removed when loading workbooks according to doc. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/changes.html

So you only need to remove the keyword from the load method and if you only want to ignore the first row use row_offset=1